# NSString in Reverse order Arabic in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am integrate My App supporting for Arabic Characters.

**How to Get the Reverse order in Arabic strings?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following Code.

All NSStrings are Same Procedure to Reverse the Strings

```
NSString *reverse=@"الكتب";
NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString string];
NSInteger charIndex = [reverse length];
while (charIndex > 0) {
    charIndex--;
    NSRange subStrRange = NSMakeRange(charIndex, 1);
    [reversedString appendString:[reverse substringWithRange:subStrRange]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", reversedString);
```