# Arabic Strings reversed in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a problem with my Xcode, For example i'm gonna to `NSLog @"سلام";` when i did writing it'll show `NSLog @"مالس";`. They are reveresed. I'm asking this for both Arabic and Persian!
tnx!

Comment: Seems like you have to reverse it. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987027/nsstring-in-reverse-order-arabic-in-iphone

Comment: This appears to have been finally fixed in Xcode 5 (مرحى).

Answer (score 1):

Actually its problem with Editor so change the Editor as in my case I opened file in **TextEdit** and wrote Arabic and Persian which worked correctly for me.